# How to make cleaner domain class inheritance with EF Core entity model mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

## Explain

Here is simplified circumstance.
I have two projects.

- `Application.BusinessLogic`
- `Application.Infrastructure`

I want to keep infrastructure code (EF Core) out from business logic.

### Application.BusinessLogic

I have following two class in `Application.BusinessLogic` project.

#### class `Game`

```cs
public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<User> Users { get; }
}
```

#### class `GameFps`

```cs
public class GameFps : Game
{
    public int Kill { get; set; }
}
```

### Application.Infrastructure

Seperate EF Core specific code from `Application.BusinessLogic`.

#### class `Game`

```cs
// There are serveral reasons I need to create this class.
// For example, Maybe someone has no control over business logic code. But, need to add extra field.
// `LazyLoader` is just an example to show you how much I want to seperate between business logic and infrastructure code.
internal class GameEntity : BusinessLogic.Game
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-without-proxies

    private List<User>? _usersEntity;

    private Printer(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    public override IReadOnlyCollection<User> Users => _usersEntity.AsReadOnly();

    internal List<User> UsersEntity
    {
        get
        {
            LazyLoader?.Load(this, ref _usersEntity);
            if (_usersEntity is null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            return _usersEntity;
        }
    }
}
```

#### ApplicationDbContext

```cs
internal class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<GameEntity> Games { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        ConfigureGameModel(modelBuilder.Entity<GameEntity>());
        ConfigureGameFpsModel(modelBuilder.Entity<GameFps>());

        // ...
    }

    private static void ConfigureGameModel(EntityTypeBuilder<Game> builder)
    {
        // ...

        builder
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Genre")
            .HasValue<GameFps>("FPS");

        // ...
    }
}
```

### EF Core migrations

When run below script,

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddGameFps
```

I get an exception like below.

```bash
Cannot configure the discriminator value for entity type 'GameFps' because it doesn't derive from 'GameEntity'.
```

I understand my current situation. But, I can't figure out a solution to this.

### Problem

Cannot inherit from `GameEntity`.

```cs
namespace Application.Infrastructure;

// Imposibble to inherit two class at once.
public class GameFpsEntity : GameEntity, GameFps
{
    // ...
}
```

### Reference

[EF Core > Create a model > Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)

Comment: In the example that you provided, the domain models are also used as entities, and that is why they don't need multiple inheritance. If you want your persistence and business logic to be completely separated, then you might consider mapping between entities and domain models (with whatever technique you like best: automapper, constructor, setters, reflection...).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Do you mean [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)? I already using it to mapping from entity object to data transfer object. Can you give me any reference Github repository, which mapping between domain and entity? That will be nice getting start point to me. I need a clue for making repository pattern based on what you suggest.

Comment: For simplicity, people tend to reuse the domain models in the persistence layer, but when that is not possible, then they create separate classes for everything and map between them. One solution for it is automapper but not everybody likes it. Their [getting started](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) section is a good place to check if it fits your style.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Thanks! What you pointed out to me is clear enough to try out. I will answer my own question with what you suggest when I solve my problem.

Comment: @ibocon the problems are caused by the code itself, not EF. EF Core like all ORMs deal with plain C# objects. EF does support plain old inheritance. It can store both Game and GameFps, in the same or different tables. It doesn't need an extra `GameEntity` class. There's no inheritance relation between GameEntity and GameFps. That's what EF complains about

Comment: `ILazyLoader` is needed only when you want to use lazy loading explicitly, for some relations. Do you *really* want that? In most cases that can lead to performance problems. In most cases and definitely most web applications it's better to use `Include()` to explicitly load the related entities you need at the time of the call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I will consider using `Include()` rather than `ILazyLoader`. However, It is a simplified example. And the point of my question is how to seperate between business logic layer's domain model and persistence layer's entity model. There are several reasons why `GameEntity` is required. Sorry for misleading context.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my question. Thanks to sharing your time while taking care of 6 children. Would you mind if I ask you what is your opinion about Octavian Mărculescu's suggestion?